# Error creating group with ansible sudo/become

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a gropu with Ansible, which fails but works if I run it as an SSH command.

The Play

```yaml
- name: Test error creating groups
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: xdradmin
  tasks:
  - name: Ensure test group exists
    group:
      name: test
      state: present
      gid: 1001
```

Attempting to create the group fails with error.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i web, -u xdradmin test.yml 

PLAY [Test error creating groups] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [web]

TASK [Ensure test group exists] **********************************************************************************************
fatal: [web]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "groupadd: Permission denied.\ngroupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.\n", "name": "test"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
web                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

However if I do essentially the same thing manually, it works fine.

```
 ssh xdradmin@web 'sudo groupadd -g 1001 test && tail -n1 /etc/group'
test:x:1001:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have told ansible to become (sudo in this case) to the user `xdradmin`, which apparently has no permission to create groups. Most of the time you should become `root` as this is the administrative user that will do all the tasks that require root privilege. Indeed, it's what you did with your ssh command: you became `root`, not `xdradmin`. Thus the command worked.

Fix your `become_user`, e.g.:

```
become_user=root
```

The become user is different to the user that ansible connects to the remote system as. That is `remote_user`.

```
remote_user=xdradmin
```

With these two changes, ansible will ssh to the system as user `xdradmin`, then sudo to `root` and finally run your task.